# iOS App on IPad removing dot decimal value

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin

I am making a iOS app in xamarin. I am working with decimal values & everything works great on the iPhone. But when I test the app on a iPad, 1 (not all) decimal value get's misinterpreted.

For exemple there is a string value : 1200.00.
I am Parsing this value :

```
if (Decimal.TryParse (vehicle.offer_price, out result)) {
```

but I am getting back : 120000 on the iPad & 1200.00 on the iPhone?
What's up with this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the internal implementation of Decimal with how it is presented. Floating point types (decimal, double etc) are implemented as binary data structures, which can be presented to us in an number of different formats (depending on where they are being displayed), which may or may not include the significant digits after the decimal point. Normally in the UI it is up to you the programmer to decide what display format to use (e.g., how many digits after the decimal point).

Compare this to the debugger - here the display format has been chosen by the implementors of the IDE, who may or may not include digits after the decimal point (but it would be a bit odd if they did not display any).

The important thing is, whatever the display format, this does not change the actual underlying value in the Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

The region settings on each device is different.

One device is set to a region format where the dot is a thousand separator, the other where it's a decimal separator.